# Securing jquery script from "FIREBUG"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, firebug

I got to write a jquery script like

`function DeleteFile(_FileID)
{
//ajax method to delete the file
}`

and the fileId id present in the rel attribute of the list

Now my problem is..when I called "DeleteFile" from firebug by passing the fileId(which i know from the rel), the file actually gets deleted...
What could be the solution to this problem???

Comment: What else would you expect to happen? :S

Comment: That doesn't look particularly like a "jquery script".

Comment: Assuming from your title you expect that NOT to happen, try doing a closure on your JS. Removing the function from global scope. You should know that JS is not secure, with enough JS-fu you can bypass even closures.

Comment: So, you want to stop firebug from calling your javascript code? You can not secure or trust anything on a client...

Comment: why is it a problem? If you wan't to prevent users from executing javascript on your page in another way than through your forms, you can't. You'll have to think of some way to check serverside (in the code you use to respond to the ajax request)

Comment: Why not perform checks server side if your script can currently be used maliciously. And it is JavaScript, not jQuery you are writing in. jQuery makes some things easier in JavaScript, it is not a scripting language in it's self.

Comment: Your explanation is confusing & needs to be expanded!  EXAMPLE: the code shown is JavaScript not jQuery; Your signature implies a file is deleted and you said it (in fact) does delete the file...so therefore, what is wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Firebug has access to all Javascript variables and functions. So do the developer tools in the various other browsers. You cannot get around this. (In fact, because Firebug and friends are run as browser plug-ins, they actually have *more* access to some things than normal javascript that's included in a web page)

Even if Firebug didn't exist, a malicious user could use other debugging or administrator tools to sniff the HTTP query that gets generated by your `DeleteFile()` function and replicate the query, putting any parameter he wanted into the GET or POST. A good example of the kind of tool that can do this is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/), but there's plenty of others.

In short, the browser environment is a fundamentally insecure place, and your server should never blindly trust anything that comes from the browser.

Rather than trying to secure the `DeleteFile()` function from within the browser, which is impossible, you should instead secure the server-side code which `DeleteFile()` posts to. This code can be secured by only allowing files to be deleted which the user has legitimate access to delete.

Once that's in place, it really doesn't matter if the user starts hacking the front-end script with Firebug, because he won't be able to do anything which he isn't allowed to do anyway. The worst that can happen would be that his hacking would make the browser's display go out of sync with what is actually on the server, but that would be his own fault and his own problem; it shouldn't mean anything to the server.